# How to interpret a signed number with fractional points to actual value in C code(256 -> 4)

Tags: c, floating-point, vhdl

I have an input fed from vhdl code into Nios system programmed in C language.

In the vhdl,

```
signal input    : ufixed(9 downto -6);
```

when I fed this input to C compiler, in the terminal window, it is shown,

```
input = 256
```

In vhdl, input is declared to have 10 decimal points and 6 fractional points. So,

input in binary should look like this: `0000000100 000000` (which is equivalent to `256` in decimal)

What should I do so that I will get the "input" interpreted as value `4` in C code?

I want both integer and fractional parts, for example, if the input is `0000000100 100000` , I want to get the value of `4.5` in C code

Comment: `input >> 6` will give you the integer part. You haven't given enough clues for us to guess what you want to do with the fractional part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C code you can just divide by a scaling factor to get the equivalent value:

```
float f = (float)input / (1 << 6);   // divide by 2^6 = 64
```

If you only want the integer part then you can just shift out the fractional part:

```
int n = input >> 6;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're getting the value in an `unsigned int` variable, and only care about the integer part, one quick way would be

1. Receive the value
2. [Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) the variable value by `n` bits (known to you, the *fractional* part)
3. Store the result.

Comment: That is decimal. So divide by 1e(x), not shift. Also: shifting would discard the fraction part.

Comment: @Olaf My Bad, I though only integer part is needed. Will update